# Assembling ARM instructions on x86_64

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, gnu-assembler

I have a file, foo.S, which contains ARM thumb instructions, on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 machine.  Is it possible to convert this into an ARM object file using `as` from `binutils` or do I need to create a cross-compiler toolchain?  I tried

```bash
$ as -mthumb foo.S -o foo.o
```

However, I got

```
as: unrecognized option '-mthumb'
```

even though that's one of the options listed in `man as`.

Comment: You need to download and install a separate toolset for ARM, e.g. https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads if you are targeting embedded devices without an operating system.

Comment: Thanks!  Want to post that as the answer?

Comment: Or `apt install binutils-arm-none-eabi`.

Comment: @NateEldredge, still getting the same error after installing that package.  Does the package install a different `as` binary?

Comment: you then use arm-none-eabi-as

Comment: if you install gcc-arm-none-eabi then binutils and perhaps others are automatically installed and you have C and asm and binutils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
sudo sh -c 'apt update;apt install binutils-arm-none-eabi;'
```

then the code can be compiled with

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mthumb foo.S -o foo.o
```

example:

```
$ echo nop > foo.S 
$ arm-none-eabi-as -mthumb foo.S -o foo.o
$ echo $?
0
$ file foo.o
foo.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

- i gathered this from  @Nate Eldredge and @old_timer in the comments.

Comment: Those are very good comments, but they do not address the `.S` versus `.s` thing IMHO - in this specific case, this is `arm-none-eabi-gcc` which is needed, not `arm-none-eabi-as`- my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

A minimal and deterministic procedure for assembling a .S file targeting the T32 instruction set on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 machine could be to install the latest [Arm toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads) for [arm-none-eabi](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.3.rel1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz?rev=95edb5e17b9d43f28c74ce824f9c6f10&hash=176C4D884DBABB657ADC2AC886C8C095409547C4)

if you don't have `wget` installed, just execute:
`sudo apt-get install wget`, or download  `arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz` using a WEB browser into you home directory.

Once done:

```
cd ${HOME}
# Skip the wget command hereafter if arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz was already downloaded into your home directory.
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.3.rel1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz?rev=95edb5e17b9d43f28c74ce824f9c6f10&hash=176C4D884DBABB657ADC2AC886C8C095409547C4" -O arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz
tar Jxf arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz
```

You can now assemble your program using the command:

```
${HOME}/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mthumb foo.S -o foo.o
```

Please note that a file with the .S extension usually requires to be processed using cpp, the C preprocessor - this is why the command is using `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, and not `arm-none-eabi-as`.